# Inserting data from one table into another

Tags: mysql, insert

There is a one table,

```
City[city_id,state_id]
```

There was another table in same database,

```
Registration[reg_id,city_id]
```

Now, i have added one more column into 'Registration' table, so it is become as shown below,

```
    Registration[reg_id,city_id,state_id]
```

But, the problem is that values of the state_id column is '0'. So, How can i insert value of state_id column of "Registration" table from the "City" table according to matching city_id value of "Registration" table.

Comment: is state_id in Registration table has the same value as state_id in City table? if yes, then you're doing a database design flaw. a referred entry should be and only be referenced by its primary key.

Comment: @LeleDumbo: don't be so categorical - denormalization is a common practice for such sort of entities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as this query will be performed just once - you could use this not efficient, but readable query:

```
UPDATE Registration r
   SET state_id = (SELECT state_id
                     FROM City c
                    WHERE c.city_id = r.city_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work in MySQL. In the background it instruct the server to make inner join on two tables.

```
UPDATE Registration r, City c SET r.state_id = c.state_id WHERE r.city_id = c.city_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure about MySQL, but that's how it can be done in Oracle and SQL Server:

```
UPDATE Registration r SET state_id = (SELECT state_id FROM City WHERE city_id = r.city_id)
```